# How does Google determine to index pages as discussion pages?

Tags: search, seo, forum

I am building a question and answering site by myself. 
I want to make this site indexed as a Q&A site or Forums by Google, which can be retrieved when using the "Discussions" in Google. In my personal experience, Google Discussion Search is a pretty useful function when I want to get others' real opinions or experience.

However, I have no any idea on that how Google determine one site as Q&A/Forum or one page as Q&A/Forum page. I searched a lot on Google, but there is little related information discussing this issue. Do you have any idea or reference on that?

Thanks!

Best,
Jing

Answer (score 0):

Use [richsnippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) and make Google recognizing your traffic by using [Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) or [Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) . Use a sitemap.xml to invite for revisit and fast indexing, disable archiving (f.e. Google Cache) with meta-robots noarchive. If you have high traffic and fast content building, search-engines will then recognize by themselves.